# How to read pickled file uploaded on Google Colab

Tags: pickle, google-colaboratory

I have uploaded pickled file on google colab using

`from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()`

Say my pickled file name is Train.p, how do I use it using typical functions, I have tried the code below but it does not work.

```
with open(io.StringIO(uploaded['train.p']), 'rb') as file:
train = pickle.load(file)
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: Did you figure out this? I have the same issue here and I am not able to read a pickle file in colab.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
import io
train = pickle.load(io.BytesIO(uploaded[‘train.p’]))
```